# Can I use the progressive form in that case

Tags: present-continuous

You are late!! Have you been missing your train once more?

Can I use the progressive form as in this case it is something he has done regurlarly

Your hair, they are green !! What have you been doing?

Same question can I use a progressive form as I'm not  happy to see his hair green

Comment: *Hair* is singular, **Your hair, it's green** and it sounds awkward to say **What have you been doing?**. I'd say **What were you doing?**

Comment: In the first example I'd use **did**, **You are late! Did you miss your train as usual?** Here *as usual* implies a habitual action.

Comment: Why does it sound awkwards?Could you explain it to me  In both cases in my mind  the activities have just ended

Comment: The first sentence sounds as if the person was missing it on purpose over and over during some time. The second sentence sounds as if it's no way connected with the fact that his hair is green. Another possible structure is **"What have you done?"** but implies a very different meaning.

Comment: you mean that you did not choose to miss your train, it is not a voluntary action   and in the second example if i add what have you been doing with your hair? , it is connected now    thanks for you explaination

Comment: It's **to your hair** and not **with your hair**.

Comment: in that case does it work   What have you been doing to your hair

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59402/discussion-between-user5577-and-sovereignsun).

Answer (score -1):

I would say:

> You're late,are you going to miss your train again?

or:

> ... are you missing your train again?

The example with hair sounds okay.

If you're unhappy with someone's habit, you can use present continuous in this way:

> You're always leaving the door unlocked!

Comment: Why is it not possible to use present perfect with the first example    youre late !!!!! you have been missing your train once more. Yes I  know we can use present continuous but we can also use present perfct continuous  so what is the difference

Comment: @user5577 Have been doing  puts emphasis that the action has been done from some, perhaps unspecified point in the past and either has just ended or is still being done. When talking about train, emphasis is rather on the current state if being late and missing the train.